# How do I fix a name error when I ask for a value before it is defined no matter how it's arranged?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a small login command that I'll edit to change "lbl3", but for now this is what I have. It's rough, and I'm fairly sure that there are more issues in this than just a name error. That's all I can really come up with in terms of details I'm afraid, as that really is my only goal. I just want to see if there's anything I can do to fix this name error, and stackoverflow isn't letting me post this question without adding more details.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to Repl.it")
window.geometry('480x270')

lbl = Label(window, text="Username")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

lbl2 = Label(window, text="Password")
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=1)

lbl3 = Label(window, text="Hidden")
lbl3.grid(column=1, row=10)
lbl3['foreground']="red"
lbl3['width']=20

txt = Entry(window,width=15)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

txt2 = Entry(window,width=15)
txt2.grid(column=1, row=1)

btn = Button(window, text="Login", command = login())
btn.grid(column=2, row=7)

btn2 = Button(window, text="Create Account")
btn2.grid(column=0, row=7)


users = { "theatrechick25" : "2Bornot2B", "soccerGuy2024" : "getYourKick$"}
realusers = []
pwds = []
def login():
  for x in users:
    realusers.append(str(x))
  print(realusers)
  for x in users:
    pwds.append(users[x])
  print(pwds)

  user = txt.get()
  pwd = txt2.get()

  if(user in realusers):
    print("succeed")
    if(pwd in users):
      print("Logged in!")
    else:
      print("failed")
  else:
    print("failed")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you called `login()` before it is defined.  For your case, simply change `command=login()` to `command=lambda: login()`.

Comment: @acw1668 even better if you use `command=login` without the `lambda` and the brackets.

Comment: Also you have to move the definition of the `login` function to the top of the code.

Comment: @TheLizzard That is why I said *"simply"* because it does not require to change or move other part of the code.

Comment: @acw1668 Good point. I forgot that the `lambda` will resolve the `login` function when it is called not when it is created. I still think that it's more pythonic to just move the function definitions at the top of the code - after the `import`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *


def login():
    for x in users:
        realusers.append(str(x))
    print(realusers)
    for x in users:
        pwds.append(users[x])
    print(pwds)

    user = txt.get()
    pwd = txt2.get()

    if user in realusers:
        print("succeed")
        if pwd in users:
            print("Logged in!")
    else:
        print("failed")
    else:
        print("failed")


window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to Repl.it")
window.geometry("480x270")

lbl = Label(window, text="Username")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

lbl2 = Label(window, text="Password")
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=1)

lbl3 = Label(window, text="Hidden")
lbl3.grid(column=1, row=10)
lbl3['foreground']="red"
lbl3['width']=20

txt = Entry(window,width=15)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

txt2 = Entry(window,width=15)
txt2.grid(column=1, row=1)

btn = Button(window, text="Login", command=login)
btn.grid(column=2, row=7)

btn2 = Button(window, text="Create Account")
btn2.grid(column=0, row=7)


users = {"theatrechick25" : "2Bornot2B", "soccerGuy2024" : "getYourKick$"}
realusers = []
pwds = []

window.mainloop()
```

I changed `command=login()` to `command=login` so it doesn't get executed before you press the button. Also I moved the definition of `login` to the top of the code otherwise you will get an error.